# Unity WWW local image URL

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on android gallery using Unity and Eclipse.

I have managed to obtain URLs like "content://com.android.providers...." or getting "/document/image:123".

However, I am not sure what to put into the parameter for WWW.
When I use

> WWW ("/document/image:123");

i will get file not found exception.

When using

> WWW ("file://content://com.android.providers....");

I will get "Open Image Error: content//com.android.providers..... is not an absolute path.

Can someone please guide me on how this work?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Both `file://` and `content://` are protocols - you must use one of them. Unity suggests using `file://`.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Also do you have access to file (app is allowed to read it) ? This has worked for me: `WWW www = new WWW("file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/my-file.txt");`

Comment: When I am using only content://, I received an error unknown protocol that is why I also tried adding file haha.

By access to file, I have added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Is that enough?

I am trying to get an image that I have chosen from the android gallery. I am using WWW www = new WWW (.....) but I am getting errors like "not an absolute path".

Any idea that might work?

Comment: Try printing out full file path and open it on you computer (if you are running in editor) or in your device. If you are able to open it, you must be able to open with Unity.

Answer (score 2):

When working with WWW class, you should use **file://** protocol to load local files in **Application.persistentDataPath**. Please also keep in mind, when using file protocol on **Windows** and **Windows Store Apps** for accessing local files, you have to specify **file:///** (with **three slashes**):  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

You can use the System.Url class to convert a local path to URL, and it should work on all platforms.

```
public static string GetFileURL(string path)
{
    return (new System.Uri(path)).AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you by chance trying to open a file in your `StreamingAssets` folder?  If so you will need to extract it from the jar file using the `WWW` class.  The path you want is:

```
string path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";
```

Comment: Nope, not dealing with streamingassets.